# Attempting to trigger a dynamic function

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden input that has a dynamic `mediaId` inserted into it using `innerHTML`. I need to be made aware when this value changes so I wanted to use this function below.

Where the value is being changed, I am calling the `setMediaId` function below and I can successfully alert the id ever time it changes.

The problem I am having now is that the `dynamicChange` function never seems to fire. What am I doing wrong?

```
    function setMediaId(v) {
      $(document).ready(function(){
alert(v);
         $('#mediaid').val(v).trigger('dynamicChange');

         $('#mediaid').on('dynamicChange', function() {
           alert();
         });

      });
    }
```

Comment: remove $(document).ready(function(){ } inside function definition.

Comment: Using `$(document).ready(function(){` inside a function is almost always wrong (or unnecessary).

Answer (score 0):

First of all no need `$(document).ready(function(){` if you are defining function and calling function directly.

Try as

```
function setMediaId(v) {
    alert(v);
    $('#mediaid').val(v).trigger('dynamicChange');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#mediaid').on('dynamicChange', function() {
       alert();
     });
  });
```

Comment: Ok, let me just say that I'm super new to JQ. That said, I thought that the ready function was for JQ functions. If I remove it, will `$('#mediaid').val(v).trigger('dynamicChange');` still be executed?

Comment: @user1709311: Maybe you want to read http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/, especially http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/.

Comment: Thanks for the link, Felix. I'll bookmark it and read through it. I certainly need something to help me with the basics.

Comment: Amit, I tried this code that you posted but nothing happens. If I comment out the first `alert(v)`, I should still expect to see the second `alert()` if mediaId fired but I don't.

Comment: as @FelixKling told need to understand basic. This is just advice how to resolve your problem.